# Improve performances of joining multiple select statements

Tags: sql, join, nested

Here we join multiple select statements in a stored procedure. In each nested query, we put filter on the year parameter and a bunch of others. I am sure there is redundancy that harms performance but not sure how exactly to improve. Any idea? Thanks!

```
SELECT Months.MonthName, 
GPSDailyAccruals.MonthNumber,
GPSDailyAccruals.YearNumber,
ISNULL(GPSDailyAccruals.Amount,0) AS GPSDailyAccrualAmount,
ISNULL(GPSMonthlyAccruals.Amount,0) AS GPSMonthlyAccrualAmount,
ISNULL(GPSMonthlyAccrualsReceivable.Amount,0) AS GPSMonthlyAccrualReceivableAmount,
ISNULL(GMIDailyAccruals.Amount,0) AS GMIDailyAccrualAmount,
ISNULL(GLPayable.AMOUNT,0) AS GLPayable,
+ISNULL(Paid.AMOUNT,0) AS Paid,
ISNULL(GMIDailyAccruals.Amount,0)-ISNULL(Paid.AMOUNT,0) AS GMIvsPAID,
ISNULL(AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount.Amount,0) AS AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount,
ISNULL(GMIDailyAccruals.Amount,0) + ISNULL(AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount.Amount,0) - ISNULL(GLPayable.AMOUNT,0) AS GLOOB,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(MatchedTrades.Amount,0) <> 0 AND ISNULL(TotalTrades.Amount,0) <> 0  THEN (CONVERT(numeric,MatchedTrades.Amount) / CONVERT(numeric,TotalTrades.Amount)) * 100 ELSE 0 END AS MatchingPercentage

FROM
(
    SELECT Months.MonthNumber, 
    Months.MonthName
    FROM Months
) Months

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MONTH(TradeDate) AS MonthNumber,
YEAR(TradeDate) AS YearNumber,
SUM(CASE WHEN RecordType = 'C' THEN Fee ELSE Fee*-1 END) AS Amount
FROM vFutureCMEGPSPay
WHERE YEAR(TradeDate) = @year
AND StatusID <> 4
AND IsCancel = 'N'
GROUP BY MONTH(TradeDate), YEAR(TradeDate)
) GPSDailyAccruals
ON Months.MonthNumber = GPSDailyAccruals.MonthNumber

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MonthNumber,
YearNumber,
SUM(CASE WHEN RecordType = 'C' THEN Fee ELSE Fee*-1 END) AS Amount
FROM TradeCMEGPSMonthly
WHERE YearNumber = @year
AND Expired_CarryoverIndicator NOT IN ('E','C')
GROUP BY MonthNumber, YearNumber
) GPSMonthlyAccruals
ON Months.MonthNumber = GPSMonthlyAccruals.MonthNumber

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MonthNumber,
YearNumber,
SUM(Fee) AS Amount
FROM TradeCMEGPSMonthly
WHERE YearNumber = @year
AND RecordType = 'E'
AND Expired_CarryoverIndicator NOT IN ('E','C')
GROUP BY MonthNumber, YearNumber
) GPSMonthlyAccrualsReceivable
ON Months.MonthNumber = GPSMonthlyAccrualsReceivable.MonthNumber

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MONTH(TradeDate) AS MonthNumber,
YEAR(TradeDate) AS YearNumber,
SUM(CASE WHEN AssetClassCode = 'Z' THEN PCOMM * -1 ELSE POTHER END)*-1 AS Amount
FROM vFutureCMEGPSGMIPay
WHERE YEAR(TradeDate) = @year
AND StatusID <> 4
GROUP BY MONTH(TradeDate), YEAR(TradeDate)
) GMIDailyAccruals
ON Months.MonthNumber = GMIDailyAccruals.MonthNumber

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
MonthNumber,
YearNumber,
SUM(AMOUNT)*-1 AS Amount
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM GMIGeneralLedger
    WHERE YearNumber = @year
    AND GL_ACCOUNT_NBR = '4402795'
    AND ATTRIBUTE1 NOT LIKE '%GPS SETTLEMENT%'
    ) GMIGeneralLedger
GROUP BY MonthNumber, YearNumber
) GLPayable
ON Months.MonthNumber = GLPayable.MonthNumber

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
MonthNumber,
YearNumber,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS Amount
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM GMIGeneralLedger
    WHERE YearNumber = @year
    AND GL_ACCOUNT_NBR = '4402795'
    AND ATTRIBUTE1 LIKE '%GPS SETTLEMENT%'
    ) GMIGeneralLedger
GROUP BY MonthNumber, YearNumber
) Paid
ON Months.MonthNumber = Paid.MonthNumber    

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT AdjustmentMonth,
AdjustmentYear,
SUM(Amount)*-1 AS Amount
FROM AdjustmentFutureWFSPayable
WHERE ModuleID = 9
AND AdjustmentYear = @year
GROUP BY AdjustmentMonth, AdjustmentYear
) AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount
ON Months.MonthNumber = AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount.AdjustmentMonth

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MONTH(TradeDate) AS MonthNumber,
YEAR(TradeDate) AS YearNumber,
COUNT(TradeStatusID) AS Amount
FROM TradeCMEGPS
INNER JOIN TradeStatus ON TradeCMEGPS.TradeID = TradeStatus.TradeID AND ModuleID = 9 AND SourceSystemID = 7
WHERE YEAR(TradeDate) = @year
AND TradeStatus.StatusID <> 4
GROUP BY MONTH(TradeDate), YEAR(TradeDate)
) TotalTrades
ON Months.MonthNumber = TotalTrades.MonthNumber

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MONTH(TradeDate) AS MonthNumber,
YEAR(TradeDate) AS YearNumber,
COUNT(TradeStatusID) AS Amount
FROM TradeCMEGPS
INNER JOIN TradeStatus ON TradeCMEGPS.TradeID = TradeStatus.TradeID AND ModuleID = 9 AND SourceSystemID = 7
WHERE YEAR(TradeDate) = @year
AND MatchingGroupID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(TradeDate), YEAR(TradeDate)
) MatchedTrades
ON Months.MonthNumber = MatchedTrades.MonthNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many wrong things here, multiple joins with the same base table and logic, just to get another calculation, do those in the same join. You also kept grouping by year, when it wasn't necessary. Here is a version (that might have a typo somewhere), that follows the advice that I just gave you:

```
SELECT  Months.MonthName, 
        GPSDailyAccruals.MonthNumber,
        @year YearNumber,
        ISNULL(GPSDailyAccruals.Amount,0) AS GPSDailyAccrualAmount,
        ISNULL(GPSMonthlyAccruals.Amount,0) AS GPSMonthlyAccrualAmount,
        ISNULL(GPSMonthlyAccruals.AmountReceivable,0) AS GPSMonthlyAccrualReceivableAmount,
        ISNULL(GMIDailyAccruals.Amount,0) AS GMIDailyAccrualAmount,
        ISNULL(GLPayable.AMOUNT*-1,0) AS GLPayable,
        ISNULL(GLPayable.AMOUNT,0) AS Paid,
        ISNULL(GMIDailyAccruals.Amount,0)-ISNULL(GLPayable.AMOUNT,0) AS GMIvsPAID,
        ISNULL(AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount.Amount,0) AS AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount,
        ISNULL(GMIDailyAccruals.Amount,0) + ISNULL(AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount.Amount,0) - ISNULL(GLPayable.AMOUNT*-1,0) AS GLOOB,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(TotalTrades.Amount2,0) <> 0 AND ISNULL(TotalTrades.Amount1,0) <> 0  THEN (CONVERT(numeric,TotalTrades.Amount2) / CONVERT(numeric,TotalTrades.Amount1)) * 100 ELSE 0 END AS MatchingPercentage
FROM
(
    SELECT Months.MonthNumber, 
    Months.MonthName
    FROM Months
) Months
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  MONTH(TradeDate) AS MonthNumber,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN RecordType = 'C' THEN Fee ELSE Fee*-1 END) AS Amount
            FROM vFutureCMEGPSPay
            WHERE YEAR(TradeDate) = @year
            AND StatusID <> 4
            AND IsCancel = 'N'
            GROUP BY MONTH(TradeDate)) GPSDailyAccruals
    ON Months.MonthNumber = GPSDailyAccruals.MonthNumber
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  MonthNumber,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN RecordType = 'C' THEN Fee ELSE Fee*-1 END) AS Amount,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN RecordType = 'E' THEN Fee END) AmountReceivable
            FROM TradeCMEGPSMonthly
            WHERE YearNumber = @year
            AND Expired_CarryoverIndicator NOT IN ('E','C')
            GROUP BY MonthNumber) GPSMonthlyAccruals
    ON Months.MonthNumber = GPSMonthlyAccruals.MonthNumber
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  MONTH(TradeDate) AS MonthNumber,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN AssetClassCode = 'Z' THEN PCOMM * -1 ELSE POTHER END)*-1 AS Amount
            FROM vFutureCMEGPSGMIPay
            WHERE YEAR(TradeDate) = @year
            AND StatusID <> 4
            GROUP BY MONTH(TradeDate)) GMIDailyAccruals
    ON Months.MonthNumber = GMIDailyAccruals.MonthNumber
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  MonthNumber,
                    SUM(AMOUNT) AS Amount
            FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT *
                    FROM GMIGeneralLedger
                    WHERE YearNumber = @year
                    AND GL_ACCOUNT_NBR = '4402795'
                    AND ATTRIBUTE1 NOT LIKE '%GPS SETTLEMENT%'
                  ) GMIGeneralLedger
            GROUP BY MonthNumber) GLPayable
    ON Months.MonthNumber = GLPayable.MonthNumber   
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  AdjustmentMonth,
                    SUM(Amount)*-1 AS Amount
            FROM AdjustmentFutureWFSPayable
            WHERE ModuleID = 9
            AND AdjustmentYear = @year
            GROUP BY AdjustmentMonth) AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount
    ON Months.MonthNumber = AdjustmentsLateTradeAmount.AdjustmentMonth
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  MONTH(TradeDate) AS MonthNumber,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN TradeStatus.StatusID <> 4 THEN TradeStatusID END) AS Amount1,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN MatchingGroupID IS NOT NULL THEN TradeStatusID END) AS Amount2
            FROM TradeCMEGPS
            INNER JOIN TradeStatus 
                ON TradeCMEGPS.TradeID = TradeStatus.TradeID 
                AND ModuleID = 9 AND SourceSystemID = 7
            WHERE YEAR(TradeDate) = @year
            GROUP BY MONTH(TradeDate)) TotalTrades
    ON Months.MonthNumber = TotalTrades.MonthNumber
```

Comment: I've taken your advice. Thank you so much! In additional to improving the query, I think I'll make changes to how data is stored as well so that we don't have to query the year and do calculation all the time.

Comment: @user2683470 Good that it helped you. And if you are in control of how the data is stored, then you could probably improve the performance of this type of query with some modifications.